# Link not sending to the right page

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I have this code:

```
if ($topic['user']==$_SESSION['display'])
{
    echo '<div class="bottomright"><a href="?id=<?php echo $topic_id; ?>&part=5"><img src="../assets/icons/Comments-edit.png" /></a><a href="?id=<?php echo $topic_id; ?>&part=6"><img src="../assets/icons/Lock.png" /></a><a href="?id=<?php echo $topic_id; ?>&part=7"><img src="../assets/icons/Trash.png" /></a></div>';
}
```

When I hove over the image the link shows as:

```
?id=%3C?php%20echo%20$topic_id;%20?%3E&part=3
```

Rather than:

```
?id=3&part=3
```

Why is this not working?

I tried this:

```
if ($topic['user']==$_SESSION['display'])
{
    echo '<div class="bottomright"><a href="?id=$topic_id&part=5"><img src="../assets/icons/Comments-edit.png" /></a><a href="?id=$topic_id&part=6"><img src="../assets/icons/Lock.png" /></a><a href="?id=$topic_id&part=7"><img src="../assets/icons/Trash.png" /></a></div>';
}
```

Now I get:

```
?id=$topic_id&part=3
```

Comment: You should read: [**What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: [Also you do not need to edit your question with what worked for you, just mark the answer as the right answer, see here how.](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is already within PHP tags, you don't have to add an additional `<?php` to the link's parameters.

```
echo '<div class="bottomright"><a href="'. $topic_id .'&part=5"...
```

Simply terminate your string and concatenate the relevant variables into the string.

Here is a very simplified example:

```
<?php

$user_name = "Anthony";

echo "Hello ". $user_name ."! How are you?";
//----------^ terminating the string

?>
```

This will result in:

> Hello Anthony! How are you?

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) is the relevant documentation dealing with string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You are echoing a php statement, it won't be interpreted, but displayed as it is. Instead, you should concatenate the string, like this:

```
if ($topic['user']==$_SESSION['display'])
{
    echo '<div class="bottomright"><a href="?id='
        . $topic_id
        . '&part=5"><img src="../assets/icons/Comments-edit.png" /></a><a href="?id='
        . $topic_id
        . '&part=6"><img src="../assets/icons/Lock.png" /></a><a href="?id='
        . $topic_id 
        . '&part=7"><img src="../assets/icons/Trash.png" /></a></div>'; 
}
```

Comment: +1 The only answer here that took the time to reformat the code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "echo" within a PHP statement. Just concatenate the string (here id) as shown here:

```
if ($topic['user']==$_SESSION['display']){ echo '<div class="bottomright"><a href="?id='.$topic_id.'&part=5"><img src="../assets/icons/Comments-edit.png" /></a><a href="?id='.$topic_id.'&part=6"><img src="../assets/icons/Lock.png" /></a><a href="?id='.$topic_id.'&part=7"><img src="../assets/icons/Trash.png" /></a></div>'; }
```

Also, you should use "& amp;" (without that space, don't know how to format that here) instead of "&" in your links.